# Iterate through array and play audio consecutively

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, audio

I have an input that contains strings which are separated by "/" which I then Split to create an array. Each string array item then needs to be used to populate the src attribute of an audio tag and play consecutively.

**UPDATE:** Code below now works although still needs some work.

```
$('#button').click(function(){

    // get value of input

    var y = $("#input").val();

    // split into array

    var g = y.split("/");



    var arrayLength = g.length;


    for (var i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++ ) {

    // create audio elements for each input

     var j = "<audio class='audio_play' id='" + g[i] + "' src='/sound/" + g[i] + ".mp3'></audio>";


    $('body').append(j);


}

// create array of each audio input

var arrayOfIds = $.map($(".audio_play"), function(n, i){

      return n.id;

    });

var sound1 = document.getElementById(arrayOfIds[0]);
var sound2 = document.getElementById(arrayOfIds[1]);
var sound3 = document.getElementById(arrayOfIds[2]);



sound1.play();
sound1.onended = function() {

sound2.play();

}

sound2.onended = function(){
sound3.play();
}


});
```

Comment: Do you know how to play the audio on your own, just the one? If this is a simple callback pattern question, look up the term.

Comment: Yes this plays the sound but only the last value within the array

Comment: Lookup (google). "js event handler", "js ended event" and "callback pattern" and you will solve this issue im sure. Also, note that your HTML has many elements with same ID, this is wrong, use class selector or different ids